# Add admin script to several post types

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development

I have found several tutorials how to add script to certain post type.like

```
add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-post-new.php', 'banner_admin_script', 11 );
add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-post.php', 'banner_admin_script', 11 );
function banner_admin_script() {
global $post_type;
if( $post_type == 'members' )
  wp_enqueue_script( 'portfolio-admin-script', plugins_url( '/js/admin.js', __FILE__),'','', true); //"TRUE"-ADDS JS TO FOOTER
  }
```

Now how can add this script to multiple post types?May be like this `if( $post_type == array('members','post','testimonial') )`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if( in_array($post_type, array( 'members','post','testimonial' ) ) )
  wp_enqueue_script( 'portfolio-admin-script', plugins_url( '/js/admin.js', __FILE__),'','', true);
}
```

Function `in_array` is used to check if current post type is in the array of allowed post types.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use OR(`||`) operator to test for each of the condition. OR returns `true` if any of the condition is `true`

```
 if ( ($post_type == 'members') || ($post_type == 'post') || ($post_type == 'testimonial') )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add all your post types in an array as a variable, and then pass that through a `foreach` loop

```
$post_types = array('members','post','testimonial');

foreach ($post_types as $type) {

if( $post_type == $type )
  wp_enqueue_script( 'portfolio-admin-script', plugins_url( '/js/admin.js', __FILE__),'','', true); //"TRUE"-ADDS JS TO FOOTER
}
```